# Apache Htaccess - Rewrite Rules Conflicts and/or Order

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I don't use .htaccess often, but I had to setup a local webserver recently and I ended up with the following rewrite rules:

```
# Settings: General
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Settings: Protocol
RewriteRule ^ - [env=PROTO]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=PROTO:s]

# Remove WWW (https://www.example.com/ -> https://example.com/)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Versioning (main.20150826.css -> main.css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(?:bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jp(?:eg?|g)|js|png|svgz?|tiff?|webp)$ $1.$3 [L]

# Forbidden/Missing Resources (403 if directory/file starts with '.')
RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

# Missing Resources (403 if file/directory not found)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

# Hotlinking Prevention
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(?:bmp|cur|gif|ico|jp(?:eg?|g)|png|svgz?|tiff?|webp)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:bmp|cur|gif|ico|jp(?:eg?|g)|png|svgz?|tiff?|webp)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Since I'm not really expert, I would like to know if they have been placed in the correct execution order and if there may be conflict issues with some of them!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is the correct venue for reviewing code. Rather than helping you fix something that isn't working. Is there an actual problem?

Comment: As far as I can tell, sometimes when I load webpages that shouls show a content I get a blank page or I end up with an error 500. But I'm unable to find what's wrong with this.

Comment: Turn on your PHP display errors. That's most likely your issue. I noticed you tagged the question with php and blank pages are typically fatal errors. Fatal errors will also cause a 500 error. That doesn't mean there is an issue with your rules.